# Prints end after 3 or 4 layers after upgrading stock FW to Marlin 2.0.9.3

Tags: marlin, ultimaker-cura

Finally upgraded my old stock Marlin Firmware to Marlin 2.0.9.3 (current latest release). I'm using Cura 5.0 as my slicer. Printer is a Folgertech Prusa i3, acrylic. It was working fine but I wanted access to some EEPROM settings that stock didn't have.

Everything seems fine until my prints get to about layer 3 or 4, and then suddenly the print stops, the Z-axis lifts up about 5 mm, and all motors turn off. Cura doesn't show that the print failed or anything and continues to advance the progress bar, but all temperature readings stop updating so I assume the printer has terminated the connection. Aborting the print in Cura does not fix the connection, and I can't jog motors until I unplug the USB and plug it back in. The only change I made is updating firmware, so it must be something there. Any guesses what's happening?

Comment: Layer 3 / 4 might be a misdetected thermal runaway, caused by the part cooling fan cooling down the extruder too much and it not being able to restore temperature in time (bad PID?) to prevent triggering that feature.
Try a print without the fan. If that fixes it, do a PID tune or adjust the runaway parameters